# How to solve $\sec^2x+3\csc^2x=8$

Tags: trigonometry

I have tried substitution involving the Pythagorean Identities, as well as converting to just sin and cos.  I cannot seem to manipulate the equation into a form which has a clear solution process.  Please provide help.

$$\sec^2x+3\csc^2x=8$$

Comment: start with multiplying both sides by $\sin^2 x \cos^2 x$.

Comment: @grargside: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Write $\sec^2x=1+\tan^2x, \csc^2x=1+\cot^2x=1+\dfrac1{\tan^2x}$ to form a Quadratic eqaution in $\tan^2x$

Then use  $\tan^2x=\tan^2A\implies x=n\pi\pm A$ where $n$ is any integer

Or use $\cos2x=\dfrac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}$ and $\cos2x=\cos2A\implies2x=2m\pi\pm2A$

Comment: $tan^4x-4tan^2x+3=0$

Comment: $(tan^2x-3)(tan^2x-1)=0$

$(tan^2x-3)(tanx-1)(tanx+1)=0$

Answer (score 2):

it is some time easier to the unit circle. we will take $$x = \cos t, y = \sin t $$ the important relation to remember is  $$x^2 + y^2 = 1. \tag 1$$ we can convert  $$\sec^2 t + 3\csc^2 t = 8 $$ into $$\frac 1{x^2} + \frac{3}{y^2} = 8$$ so you have $$3x^2 + y^2 = 8x^2 y^2 \tag 2 $$

you can solve $(1)$ and $(2)$ by eliminating ,say, $y$ to get $$3x^2 + 1 - x^2 =8x^2(1-x^2)$$ this is a quadratic equation in $x^2.$  that is $$8x^4+6x^2 - 1=0$$ has roots $$x^2 = \frac{-6 \pm\sqrt{68}}{16}, \, x = \pm\sqrt{\frac{-6 +\sqrt{68}}{16}}, t = 81.92^\circ, 98.07^\circ, 261.92^\circ, 278.07^\circ  $$

Comment: Note your $8x^4+6x^2 - 1=0$ should be $8x^4-6x^2+1=0$ instead, with this fairly easily factoring as $(4x^2-1)(2x^2-1)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\sec^2x=\frac1{\cos^2x}\text{ and }\csc^2x=\frac1{\sin^2x}$$

$$\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-1$$ to form a Quadratic Eqaution in $\cos2x$ on simplification